# Как скриптом добавить или редактировать поле additional Name(отчество), в гугл контактах?

Tags: google-apps-script

В общем задача из таблицы создавать контакт в гугле, но в официальном мануале (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/) не нашёл метода для того, что бы добавить или редактировать поле отчество, оно же additional Name.
Подскажите, это вообще возможно в рамках скрипта.
вот, что у меня уже написано:

```
function addCont(contact,G1,G2) {

  var cont = ContactsApp.createContact(contact.NAME[1], contact.NAME[0], contact.MAIL);
  cont.addToGroup(G1);
  cont.addToGroup(G2);
  cont.addCompany(contact.KORP,"");
  if (contact.KORP==contact.NAME[0]){
    contact.KORP = "";
  }else{
    contact.KORP = " (" + contact.KORP + ")";
    cont.setSuffix(contact.KORP.replace(" (","("));
  }
  cont.setFullName(contact.NAME[1] + " " + contact.NAME[2] + " " + contact.NAME[0] + contact.KORP);
  cont.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE, contact.PHON);
}
```

если использовать

```
cont.addCustomField("Additional Name", contact.NAME[2]);
```

то он делает отдельную запись в custom field, а мене нужно что бы он вносил данные в предназначенную для этого переменную, она предусмотрена контактами гугла, [image: Выгрузка контакта]

но как сделать туда запись, пока не нашёл, в противном случае телефон отображает контакт не корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, в стандартном списке [полей](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/field) и в расширенном списке [полей](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/extended-field) такого понятия как additionalName нет. Есть только MiddleName. Я так понимаю, связано это с тем, что у многих стран запада нет отчеств - только "[средние](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_name)" имена, которых можно давать даже несколько при рождении. Поэтому можете использовать это поле для отчества. Если же Вы желаете именно отчество как additionalName - то воспользуйтесь [addCustomField](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact#addCustomField(Object,Object)):

> Adds a custom field to the contact with either an extended or custom label.
>   The label can be either from ContactsApp.ExtendedField or a custom label string.

То есть Вы сможете задать собственное имя поля.

Comment: Пробовал, но он делает запись не в том виде, в вопросе уточнил, что получается

Comment: Поэтому я и написал, используйте для этих целей MiddleName

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Comment: Согласен с тем, что лучше использовать `ContactsApp.Field.MIDDLE_NAME`. Оно правильно отображается в телефонах

Answer (score 0):

методом научного тыка выяснил, что за отчество и поле additionalName, отвечает 
[MiddleName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact#getMiddleName())
решение:
`cont.setMiddleName(contact.NAME[2]);`